# Get greatest n numbers from an array using a "tournament" (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, tournament

I have an array e.g. of length 10:

```
Population = {1,3,4,2,7,-2,0,8,9,5}.
```

I generate two random numbers between 0-9 (e.g. 4 and 6). So then I check the 4th and 6th elements (7, 0) and the "winner" is the number that is greater. So 7 goes into the winners array (5 winners in total):

```
Winners = {7, ...}
```

Each time I want to pair up two of the remaining numbers (including the losers) and put the winner into the winners array.

The easiest way to do this would be to use a non-fixed size array of size n and remove a winner from 'population' and put it into 'winners'. Then I could generate two random numbers between 1 and n-1 and continue the process.

How could I do this using a fixed-size array in Java? How could I select two numbers from my array, ignoring any numbers that are 'winners'?

Comment: Potentially hacky, but what if you used an array of `Integer[]` and set visited values to `null`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use fixed size array then every time you pick the winner (lets say `ith position`) you will have to iterate over the array and move all elements with index `j=i+1` to `j` and then generate next random numbers between `0 to n=n-1`.

Though I would suggest easy data structure to use here would be `ArrayList`. You can dynamically remove elements from it and use its `size()` as upper cap to compute random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could determine the winner and then swap it to the back of the array:

```
int[] population = {1,3,4,2,7,-2,0,8,9,5};
private void turnament() {
    for (int i = population.length - 1; i >= population.length / 2; i--) {
        //you might want to make sure m != n.
        int m = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        int n = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * i);
        int temp = population[i];
        if (population[m] > population[n]) {
            population[i] = population[m];
            population[m] = temp;
        } else {
            population[i] = population[n];
            population[n] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This will do `population.length / 2` tournaments and write the winner to the back, so the last element will be the first winner, the second last the second winner etc.

Or as @Aniket Thakur mentions, the `ArrayList` would be a fine data structure.

Comment: sure - I voted you up, but the loop should really only iterate 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Keep an index pointing where is the start of your winners array (assuming you reuse the array). Initially, it will be n. Then get 2 random numbers with Random.nextInt(startOfWinners), swap the winner with n-1 and iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Using a standard array, you can implement a sort of randomized queue.

Basically, your queue is the population array; when you choose two opponents, you set their indexes to `null` and move the `null`s at the end of the array, while decrementing available size. Some pseudo-code to clarify:

```
1 population = [...]
2 winners = [all null here, size probably half of population.length + 1]
3 size = popoluation.length
4 opponents = nextTwoRandoms(size)
5 population[opponents.0] = null
6 population[opponents.1] = null
7 winners = addWinnerBetween(opponents)
8 population = moveNullAtTheEnd(population)
9 size = size - 2
10 repeat from step#4 until satisfied
```